# NTLM posting null parameters over wifi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, ntlm, iis-8.5

This is a very strange problem we are having.
We have an application that uses NTLM and all works well. However when we browse to the website over wifi then our post call (angularjs) works the first time:

**js**

```
$http.post('/search/test', { testString: 'test' });
```

**c#**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test(string testString)
{
}
```

As in `testString` comes through correctly as "test", but then refreshing the page causes it to come through as null. Subsequent refreshes cause this to come through as null, until we clear cache in either safari or chrome on iOS.

We have enabled remote debugging for safari on a mac to step through javascript, and the post with payload looks correct. We have enabled remote debugging on our IIS 8.5 server to step through code in our MVC 5 application. `testString` will be "test" first time, and then null all calls afterwards.

Is this some setting anyone has heard of? Perhaps some DLP endpoint intercepting this? Could MVC be stripping it somehow? I tried adding an `ActionFilterAttribute` to my Test method, and ModelState is valid. Any help would be appreciated